# text file downloaded through python and requests module has unrecognizable first two characters

Tags: python, python-requests

[update with screenshot of the opened file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8sak.png)

i am following along the below tutorials to download a text file from Gutenberg.org, however, when i open the file in finder, the first two characters are not recognizable, others looks all fine.
however, if i open it in terminal with vim, the file looks ok.

Do you have any clues on what may have caused this?

http://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11/

i'm on MacOS Mojave 10.14.2, python 3.7.2

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3  

import requests
res = requests.get('http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1322/pg1322.txt');
res.raise_for_status()
print('book length is: ' + str(len(res.text)//1024) + ' kBytes')
print('book content:\n' + res.text[:300])
bookFile = open('book.txt', 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    bookFile.write(chunk)
```

Comment: The text file looks fine to me on MacOS 10.14.3, Python 3.7.0. Can you copy-paste what you're seeing [onto the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55311817/edit)?

Comment: Maybe you are seeing a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: updated the question with the screenshot